# Can gnuplot compute and plot the delta between consecutive data points

Tags: gnuplot

For instance, given the following data file (x^2 for this example):

```
0
1
4
9
16
25
```

Can gnuplot plot the points along with the differences between the points as if it were:

```
0 0
1 1   # ( 1 - 0 = 1)
4 3   # ( 4 - 1 = 3)
9 5   # ( 9 - 4 = 5)
16 7  # (16 - 9 = 7)
25 9  # (25 -16 = 9)
```

The actual file has more than just the column I'm interested in and I would like to avoid pre-processing in order to add the deltas, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using awk?

```
plot "< awk '{print $1,$1-prev; prev=$1}' <datafilename>"
```

Answer (score 19):

[dtop's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10358314/100297) didn't work for me, but this works and is purely gnuplot (not calling awk):

```
delta_v(x) = ( vD = x - old_v, old_v = x, vD)
old_v = NaN
set title "Compute Deltas"
set style data lines
plot 'data.dat' using 0:($1), '' using 0:(delta_v($1)) title 'Delta'
```

Sample data file named 'data.dat':

```
0
1
4
9
16
25
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to do this without pre-processing:

Script for gnuplot:

```
# runtime_delta.dem script
# run with 
#     gnuplot> load 'runtime_delta.dem'
#
reset

delta_v(x) = ( vD = x - old_v, old_v = x, vD)
old_v = NaN

set title "Compute Deltas"
set style data lines

plot 'runtime_delta.dat' using 0:(column('Data')), '' using 0:(delta_v(column('Data'))) title 'Delta'
```

Sample data file 'runtime_delta.dat':

```
Data
0
1
4
9
16
25
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a version that uses arrays from Gnuplot 5.1. Using arrays allows multiple diffs to be calculated in single Gnuplot instance.

```
array Z[128]
do for [i=1:128] { Z[i] = NaN }
diff(i, x) = (y = x - Z[i], Z[i] = x, y)
```

`i` is the instance index that needs to be incremented for each use. For example

```
plot "file1.csv" using 1:(diff(1,$2)) using line, \
     "file2.csv" using 1:(diff(2,$2)) using line
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for an example from gnuplot 5.x.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another late solution, because:

- there is no need for an external program like `awk` (@Sunhwan Jo)
- definition of separate function is not really necessary (@dtop, @BorisHajduk)
- use of an array is completely unnecessary. Why a size of 128? (@Jaakko)

The principle here is basically the same like in all answers, but you don't need `awk`, nor a function nor an array.

The shortest would be something like:

```
plot FILE u 0:1 w p ti "Data", \
     y1=NaN '' u 0:(y0=y1,y1=$1,y1-y0) w l ti "Difference"
```

However, I prefer complete copy & paste scripts with nice-looking visualizations.

**Data:** `SO7249961.dat`

```
0
1
4
9
16
25
```

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=4.4.0, March 2010)

```
### plot differences
reset

FILE = "SO7249961.dat"

set offsets 1,1,1,1
set key top left noautotitle

plot FILE u 0:1 w p pt 7 lc rgb "red" ti "Data", \
       '' u 0:1 w steps lc rgb "grey" ti "Steps", \
     y1=NaN '' u 0:(y0=y1,y1=$1,(y1+y0)/2.):(sprintf("%g",y1-y0)) w labels \
       tc rgb "blue" right offset -1,0
### end of script
```

**Result:** (from windows terminal in gnuplot 4.4.0)

Actually, the first difference (here: blue 0) is not correct, (should be `NaN` and not visible) but gnuplot 4.4.0 does it like that. It will be correct for gnuplot>=4.6.0.

[image]